# Nginx and Django-socketio gives address already in use error

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi, socket.io, django-socketio

I am trying to setting up my django-socketio with uwsgi and nginx, and when I ran 
sudo uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

I got an error saying Address is already in use.
I know what the problem is, I think they problem is when I ran sudo uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini, it creates a SocketIOServer on port 80, and since my nginx is also started, it also listens to port 80. Therefore, they are conflicts, but I don't know how to solve it.

Could someone help.

My wsgi.py file looks like:

```
import os
PORT = 80

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

from socketio import SocketIOServer

print 'Listening on port %s and on port 843 (flash policy server)' % PORT
SocketIOServer(('', PORT), application, resource="socket.io").serve_forever()
```

And my nginx file looks like:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    charset     utf-8;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/nginxerror.log   ;

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/project/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at django-socketio recently, I remember I only let socketio listen on port 843.
Any reason why you need to listen on both 80 & 843?

under development, you may add open port 843, and see if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a socketio server in your wsgi file, use the built in runserver_socketio and start it on port 9000 using supervisor, then have nginx proxy any requests for /socket.io/ to port 9000